# MockGeolocation API did not show the "Allow location" popup on browser

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have created the test scripts where in Mock Geolocation API is supposed to be used. The code did not populate the "Allow location" popup.
Here's the snippet:

```
  "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = success =>  success({ coords: { latitude: 30, 
 longitude: -105, }, timestamp: Date.now() });";

 fixture`blah`.page`google.com`.clientScripts({
  content: mockGeolocationScript,
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the "Allow location" dialog doesn't appear when the test is running because it's a native dialog, so the TestCafe framework cannot process it. This behavior is correct.

You correctly mocked the "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition" function, so it should return your mocked data during test execution.

Comment: Any way to invoke the native dialog for location?

Comment: The 'Allow location' dialog will not be displayed because you override it. It's native browser behavior and it can be reproduced on any page. Could you please describe why you need to invoke it? It doesn't make sense since it is overridden and the returned value is fixed.

Comment: Since the web app is hyperlocal, the user should get a "Allow location" popup every time he uses the app. This had to be done  using Testcafe scripts and I didn't seem to find a way to invoke .

Comment: Could you please share an example of such a 'hyperlocal web app' and a TestCafe test to reproduce the issue?